# How to test exceptions in async methods

Tags: .net, async-ctp, visual-studio-2012

I'm playing around with the Visual Studio 11 Beta.

Given this code:

```
namespace KC.DataAccess.Global
{
    /// <summary>Global methods for SQL access</summary>
    public static class SQL
    {    
        public async static void ExecuteNonQuery(string ConnStr, string Query)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConnStr)) throw new ArgumentNullException("ConnStr");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Query)) throw new ArgumentNullException("Query");
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnStr);
            SqlCommand cmd = PrepSqlConnection(ref conn, Query);
            Exception exc = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                try { await Task.Run(() => cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()); break; }
                catch (Exception ex) { Thread.Sleep(50); exc = ex; }
            if (exc != null) throw new ApplicationException("Command failed after maximum attempts", exc);
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
         }
    } 
}
```

As it is an async method, the exceptions do not seem to bubble up to the calling method. I have test cases which therefore fail:

```
using Target = KC.DataAccess.Global.SQL;
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("Unit")]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
public void ExecuteNonQueryFail1()
{
    Target.ExecuteNonQuery(null, "select 1");
}
```

The validation part of ExecuteNonQuery is clearly throwing an exception in this case, and I see it throw when I debug it.

I have changed the test method to an async and the syntax to *await Task.Run(() => Target.ExecuteNonQuery())*, to no avail.

Questions:

- Is ExecuteNonQuery throwing the exception at all?
- Why isn't ExecuteNonQueryFail1 seeing the exception?
- How can I alter the test method, or the method itself, to handle the exception properly and pass the test case, without giving up the async nature of the method?

Comment: Note this same behavior occurs when I change the Target method to return a Task, and when I enable ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions in the test's config file.

Comment: You should be using `TaskEx.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your method returns `void`, there is no way how the exception could propagate to the calling code. If you change the return type to `Task`, you can now observe the exception, but you have to do that explicitly.

I think that the best way to modify your calling code is just to call [`Wait()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635.aspx). If the code in the `Task` threw an exception, `Wait()` will throw an `AggregateException` that will contain the original exception.

Comment: If you use `Wait`, then you can't use `ExpectedException`. It would be cleaner to make the test method `async Task` and have it `await` the `Task`. (This is a new feature added in VS11Beta; it wasn't in VS11DevPreview).

Comment: You could use `[ExpectedException(typeof(AggregateException))]`, but I guess that's not specific enough.

Comment: I do have an overload for task/await, but there are some SQL calls that can be done literally any time. This one is a void because I want to be able to 'fire and forget', like in the case of error logging or submitting jobs into a queue.

Comment: OK, I did what you said and it throws an AggregateException. This seems less useful than the actual exception that threw, but at least I can break it down into the aggregate Exceptions.  Now, how can I guarantee this will be run in a "fire and forget" fashion without the need to await a result?

Comment: That's simple: the method doesn't return anything, so there is nothing to await. `await ExecuteNonQuery(…)` simply won't compile. But you really shouldn't create “fire and forget” methods unless you need to. It's up to the consumer whether he wants to wait until finishes.

Comment: `async void` methods are *not* "fire and forget". If they raise an exception, they're more like "fire and crash".

Answer (score 4):

VS11 Beta has first-class support for testing methods that return `Task`.

So if you change your signature to:

```
public async static Task ExecuteNonQuery(string ConnStr, string Query)
```

then you can test it as such:

```
using Target = KC.DataAccess.Global.SQL;
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("Unit")]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
public async Task ExecuteNonQueryFail1()
{
  await Target.ExecuteNonQuery(null, "select 1");
}
```

(I have not had a chance to try out this new support myself, but I've read that this should work).

Note: You *should* return `Task` in your `async` methods unless you *must* return `void` (e.g., for an event handler). `Task` is awaitable, so the code is more reusable. I cover this in [my "Async and Await" intro blog post](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

If you do need to test an `async void` method for some reason, you need to supply your own `SynchronizationContext` to catch any exceptions (see the "Async Unit Testing" section of [Stephen Toub's recent blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/29/10274035.aspx)).

I have a couple of blog posts specifically dealing with async unit testing ([part 1](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-unit-tests-part-1-wrong-way.html), [part 2](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-unit-tests-part-2-right-way.html)). I wrote a basic Async Unit Tests project for VS2010+AsyncCTP or VS11-DevPreview, but I haven't had a chance to test it yet with VS11-Beta. It would be the easiest way to unit test `async void` methods if you need to. [[CodePlex](http://asyncunittests.codeplex.com/) | [NuGet]](https://nuget.org/packages/AsyncUnitTests-MSTest)

Comment: Your logic is sound, but it still didn't throw. See svick's answer.

Comment: Did you actually change the return type of `Target.ExecuteNonQuery` to `Task`? Wrapping it in `Task.Run` is not the same thing at all.

Comment: Yes, I changed it to Task.  All I'm looking for is a way to test it, detect exceptions, and be able to run it without waiting for it elsewhere.  Obviously I do want to wait for it from the test.